# rails select_tag "required" option not working in safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, safari, cross-browser

```
<%= select_tag 'user[wine_choice]', options_for_select([
                                            ['A', 'A'],
                                            ['B', 'B']]), 
               id: 'wine_choice', required: true, prompt: 'Please select one' %>
```

This works as expected in Chrome and Mozilla, that is, it will default to "Please select one", and upon a user's attempt to submit this form without changing it to A or B, it will prevent the form from submitting and show me an error on the form.

However, on Safari, it allows the form to be submitted without selecting either A or B.

Has anyone else ran into this problem? How can I fix it? If you require further information, please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Safari does not yet support form notification for the `required` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#search=required).  Either use JavaScript for validation as well or just ignore this entirely.  Make sure that you validate on the server side regardless.